# How to add method to jquery validation plugin to check if file exist on remote url

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a frontend form using jQuery validation Plugin to validate my fields and allow users upload images from a remote url and is all good.

The problem is that some users may send a url with a file that doesn't exists and the post will display with an empty image.

ie: http://example.com/Photoexample.jpg  <-- where Photoexample.jpg doesn't exist on that server.

This is what i have/trying so far:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(val, elem, param) {
    // param = size (en bytes) 
    // elem = element to validate (<input>)
    // val = value of the element (file name)
    return this.optional(elem) || (elem.files[0].size <= param) 
});
```

I know there's a way to do it with PHP like this :

```
$size = getimagesize($url);
if($size !== false){
    // Image exists
}else{
    // Image doesn't exist
}
```

But i don't know how to implement it with ajax.

I want to check if remote url file/content exist to avoid my form submit an empty url with a file that doesn't exist. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: There's already a method for this called `remote`, so you shouldn't need to write a custom method with ajax.  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Answer (score 1):

As you are using jQuery - You could use ajax to do something like this to check if a URL exists:

HTML

```
    <div id="result"></div>
```

SCRIPT

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'HEAD',
            url: 'http://example.com/Photoexample.jpg',
            success: function() {
                    // The URL exists
                   $('#result').text('This URL exists');
            },
            error: function() {
                    // The URL does not exist
                    $('#result').text('Sorry - This URL does not exist');
            }
        });
```

EDIT

Ok, so the above will not work cross domain, so here is an alternative solution.

We are going to attempt to load the image from the users specified URL again and check for success/fail.

First add your HTML img tag to check against with an ID:

```
<img id="imgFileLoaded" width="1" height="1" />
```

Next we can set up the jQuery to check the image:

```
// set you img url variable
var url = 'http://ir.ebaystatic.com/pictures/aw/pics/globalheader/spr11.png';

// check if img loads
$(function() {
    $("#imgFileLoaded").error(function(){
        // Img Failed
       $('#result').text('Failed.');

    }).attr('src', url);

    $('#imgFileLoaded').load(function() {
        //Img Success
        $('#result').text('Success!');

    });
});
```

You have have a test of this in the fiddle I did:

http://jsfiddle.net/dm5CU/

Comment: Yes. But im not asking to check if URL exist. Im asking to check if FILE exist on a remote URL

Comment: I see. Ok, well the above method would still work. If the user provided a URL to a file that did not exist, you would get an error.

Comment: And i guess the URL would be the (VAL) variable.. assuming that I'm using the jQuery validation plugin.. right?

Comment: So it would be like this : jQuery.validator.addMethod("check_file", function(val, elem) {

$.ajax({
  type : 'HEAD',
  url: 'val', // <-- variable to get the url that im writing in my form input
  error: function(data){
    return true; 
  },
  success: function(data){
  },  
});
}, 'error - Content/File doesn't exist');

Comment: Yeah, something like that should do it. The snippet I put up there is in basic form. But obviously you can modify it to be a bit more flexible :) Here is the snippet above in a fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/steakpi/WmEsD/)

Comment: No matter what url i set in the url variable.. it always say Sorry - This URL does not exist

Comment: Ah yes, looking at it, we are going to have cross domain issues. However, I have made an edit to the original answer with a different approach. I tested this in a fiddle and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

As Sparky mentioned it's better to use the [remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) else the code below should do the trick for cross domain checking:

```
$("<img>", { 
   src: $url, 
   load: function () { 
       // Image exists 
   },        
   error: function () { 
       // Image doesn't exist
   }
});
```

However for a synchronous checking method which only downloads the image header but which doesn't work across domains you can use steakpi's ajax method.